# Populating 2 textboxes from an option group

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an option group setup as follows:

[image]

- "Breaks and Transfers" has an option value of 1
- "Final Outcomes" has an optional value of 2
- "No End Form" has an option value of 0

The option group is bound to the red textbox so each option's option value is stored there when an option is chosen.

For reasons I'm not going to bore you with, I'd quite like to have this option group store values in 2 fields rather just the 1.

[image]

So the values of the 2 yellow text boxes would become:

- "Breaks and Transfers" = -1, 0
- "Final Outcomes" = 0, -1
- "No End Form" = 0, 0

What I can't figure out is what event or property there is that I can use that tells me which of the options has been selected in order to do the VBA to populate the 2 yellow textboxes accordingly.

The only way I can currently think of is to keep the red textbox as it is and populate the yellow textboxes from that.

[image]

I was hoping to remove the red textbox field from the database, so if anyone knows whether there is something intrinsic to the option group that indicates which option is selected then I'd love to know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option group has `Value` property that holds the selected control in the group. 
Check it in `AfterApdate` event of the group.

Comment: ahh, so it does.. y'know I tested for a `.Value` property, but it must have been on the individual option buttons rather than group

Comment: Yes `.Value` of the individual option is copied into `.Value` of the group when selection changed.